# How to propagate Livedata from Repository > ViewModel > Fragment

Tags: kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

`getMoreData()` in ViewModel is called from outside of ViewModel, everytime user scroll to the bottom of RecyclerView.

`fetchMore()` in Repository returns a LiveData with `LoadingStatus` object which contains loading/success/failure and error message

How can I set the `loadingStatus` variable in ViewModel so that it can be observed properly by the Fragment?

Note: `getMoreData()` in ViewModel can be called multiple times as the user scrolls down.

```
ViewModel{
    val loadingStatus

    fun getMoreData(){
        repository.fetchMore()
    }
}

Repository{
    fun fetchMore() : LiveData<LoadingStatus>{

    }
}

Fragment{
    viewModel.loadingStatus.observe()
}
```

Comment: Consider using [Paging Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/) to achieve better result

Comment: @Ollaw I am using paging library. The call to `getMoreData()` is coming from `PagedList.BoundaryCallback`

Comment: That's right. The issue is with subsequent call from `onItemAtEndLoaded` of `BoundaryCallback` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the need for a **Lifecycle Owner** used for observations of LiveData in the Repository.

First, you don't want to return a new `LiveData<LoadingStatus>` every time `fetchMore()` is called. That would create a new LiveData each time. Best case, you would want the function `fetchMore()` do some something like this, updating a single LiveData:

```
Repository{
    val status = LiveData<LoadingStatus>()

    fun fetchMore() {
        status.postValue(LOADING)

        // Pseudo code for actually loading more items

        status.postValue(FINISHED LOADING)
    }
}
```

However, you will have the issue of observing the `status` from the `ViewModel` as it itself is not a Lifecycle implementation, so it cannot easily observe the LiveData from the Repository.

My suggestion would be something like this:

```
ViewModel{
    val loadingStatus: MutableLiveData<LoadingStatus>

    init{
        repository.observeStatus()
            .subscribe( event -> loadingStatus.postValue(event))
    }

    fun getMoreData(){
        repository.fetchMore()
    }
}

Repository{
    val status = BehaviorSubject.create<LoadingStatus>()

    fun observeStatus(): Observable<LoadingStatus> {
        return status
    }

    fun fetchMore(){
        status.onNext(LOADING)

        // Pseudo code for actually loading more items

        status.onNext(FINISHED LOADING)
    }
}

Fragment{
    viewModel.loadingStatus.observe()
}
```

Note that you will have to dispose the subscription in the ViewModel onCleared. 
Note that all of this is pseudo code and it should be done a lot cleaner than this.

Comment: How about passing the MutableLiveData, created from viewModel and observed by View, to Repository and then let it update the Livedata when data is ready??